# While loop user input

Tags: powershell, parameters, while-loop

Started a new question since new approach.
old thread here: [Catching error in validatescript to custom error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45298777/)

So I have a param is used for defining a date, it's need to be in format yyyy-mm-dd.

If it's not in the right format, can't verify as datetime or null i want it to keep asking, so was thinking a while loop would work but can't figure out how to finish.

```
    Param (
          [parameter(mandatory=$false)][alias('d')][string]$date #date in format yyyy-mm-dd
           )

       if ($date){
    try {get-date($date)}
    catch{
        While($date -ne $null){
            Write-host "The Date is invalid and need to be in this format, yyyy-mm-dd" -ForeGroundColor Yellow
            $date = read-host
            clear
        }
    }
}
```

this kind of works but when right format it ends up as an infinite loop.

```
 Param (
          [parameter(mandatory=$false)][alias('d')][string]$date #date in format yyyy-mm-dd
           )

       if ($date){
       do{   
    try {get-date($date)}
    catch{
            clear
            Write-host "The Date is invalid and need to be in this format, yyyy-mm-dd" -ForeGroundColor Yellow
            $date=read-host
        }
    }
    until($date -eq $('^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$'))
    }
```

Comment: Why not just specify the parameter as type `[DateTime]`?

Comment: While I fully agree with Bill_Stewart's `[DateTime]` suggestion is the best solution, an alternative would be to use `[ValidatePattern('^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$')]`.

Comment: @BenH if you look at my original question thread, I started with validating with Datetime and validatepattern. But since I want a custom error I ended up with this solution. If you do set the param [DateTime]$date it will continue if you enter any number.

Comment: There are different errors for the transformation to `[datetime]` and validation. `ParameterArgumentTransformationError` vs `ParameterArgumentValidationError`.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart  "Param (
          [parameter(mandatory=$false)][alias('d')][Datetime]$date 
           )" will accept any number

Comment: not sure why but for me it will accept any number and continue, if you check the variable it says 1 january 0001 00:00:00 could be something with the locale since I don't have English locale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function:

```
param (
    [parameter(mandatory=$false)][alias('d')][string]$date #date in format yyyy-mm-dd
)

function IsParsable() { try { get-date($date) } catch { return $false }; return $true }

while (-not (IsParsable))
{
    clear
    Write-host "The Date is invalid and need to be in this format, yyyy-mm-dd" -ForeGroundColor Yellow
    $date = read-host
}

# do whatever you want with $date here
```